# why do changes in indetation lead to obscure results?

Tags: python, loops, indentation

```
def prod (lsts):
    product = 1
    for i in lsts:
        sum = 0
        for x in i:
            sum += x
        product *= sum # I will change this line and a problem will appear
    return product

b = [[2], [2,3,4], [5,2], []]
c = [[]]
print prod (b)
print prod (c)
```

** my first question is:
why when I change the indentation of the line with the comment like this:

```
for x in i:
    sum += x
    product *= sum # I make the line have the same indentation with the above line.
```

the result of print is not 0, but 6300 and 1?

I can figure out the result with list b, but I cannot with list c, a list with only one empty list. 
This is the process I think the program will run with list c:

1. first for loop starts.
2. second for loop starts. in second for loop, sum = 0. second for loop ends.
3. product = 0.
4. first for loop ends.  return product.
5. print

why the result of print is not 0 but 1?

** my second question is why even if I *only* change my original script in this way:

```
c = [] # in my original script, I have c = [[]]
```

the result of print also 1, not 0?

Comment: In answer to your first question -- You change the number of times that line gets executed ...

Comment: `why when I change the indentation of the line with the comment like this:` -- then `product` assignment is a part of the loop.

Comment: Remember, indentation is very, VERY important in python. moving ``product *= sum`` over to the same indentation as ``sum += x`` moves it inside the for loop

Comment: Because indentation matters in Python, and changing it changes the meaning of the program? Trick question?

Comment: In relation to your second question, if you have moved the ``product *=`` inside the for-loop, then ``product`` never gets multiplied by zero for an empty list, so it returns what it is initialized to, ``1``.

Comment: Sorry I did not explain clearly my question. with my understanding of the process of the for loop, I cannot figure out why result is 1. Is my understanding of the loop incorrect?

Comment: @aruisdante I have `sum += x`, so with list c I have `sum = 0`. So why did you say `product` never gets multiplied by `0`? I think `product` will get multiplied by `0` before the second loop end, isn't it?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill I know it will change, but with my understanding of loop I cannot explain why it change. Can you guide me through this?

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate over an empty list, your loop runs zero times - in other words, it just skips to the end immediately. So, in your original code, with `lsts=[[]]`:

```
def prod (lsts):
    product = 1
    for i in lsts:
        sum = 0
        for x in i:
            sum += x
        product *= sum # I will change this line and a problem will appear
    return product
```

it runs this way:

1. product = 1
2. for loop starts (i = [])
3. sum = 0
4. i is empty, so for loop is skipped
5. product (1) *= sum (0), so product = 0
6. no more `i`s in lsts, so for loop ends
7. return product

When you indent the line `product *= sum`:

```
def prod (lsts):
    product = 1
    for i in lsts:
        sum = 0
        for x in i:
            sum += x
            product *= sum
    return product
```

it becomes part of the inner for-loop (which runs zero times) and so it runs this way:

1. product = 1
2. for loop starts (i = [])
3. sum = 0
4. i in empty, so for loop is skipped
5. no more `i`s in lsts, so for loop ends
6. return product

Notice that in this case, product never gets reassigned after you initially set it to 1.

When you have `lsts=[]`, the entire outer for loop is skipped, so it runs like this:

1. product=1
2. lsts is empty, so for loop is skipped
3. return product

Comment: Thank you lvc. You save my day.